# Do electric fields generated by plane charges lose intensity over distance? If not, why?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields, spacetime-dimensions

Sparknotes' studyguide for the SAT II: Physics test says that for a point charge (1-dimensional, e.g. an electron), the formula for intensity of the generated electric field is given by $E=\frac{kq}{r^2}$. It also says that for a line charge (2-dimensional, e.g. a wire in a DC circuit), it's given by $E=\frac{kq}{r}$, and that for a plane charge (3-dimensional) it's given by $E=kq$. I have no example for a plane charge because I don't know what that would be, hence my question: How can a plane charge's electric field intensity NOT diminish over time? Shouldn't this violate Conservation of Energy?

Answer (score 1):

A plane charge would be an infinite 2-dimensional sheet with constant charge density. Already in a line charge you have neglected edge effects, because the $1/r$ dependence holds true only near the line provided you are far away from the end-points. Similarly, for a plane, the constant electric field holds true provided that you are much closer to the plane than you are to it's edges. You make this approximation when you derive the electric field inside a parallel plate capacitor, for example. If you truly could assemble an infinite sheet of charge, conservation of energy would be the least of your worries. Good luck with the SAT.